# What are all of the file extensions supported by FFmpeg

Tags: java, javafx, ffmpeg

How would I go about getting a list of all the file extensions supported by FFmpeg for use in an ExtensionFilter used by FileChooser in JavaFX?

I am familiar with the "-codecs" and "-formats" options from FFmpeg, but these list the format and codec names which do not necessarily coincide with their file extensions.

e.g. (partial output from "ffmpeg -formats")

- D  aac             raw ADTS AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
- DE ac3             raw AC-3
- E matroska        Matroska

parsing aac and ac3 from the output of ffmpeg would work fine to create file extensions for those types of files, but matroska has ".mkv" file extension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no list directly available. You'll have to run

for input formats,  `ffmpeg -demuxers`
   for output formats, `ffmpeg -muxers`

Then for each entry, run

for input formats,  `ffmpeg -h demuxer=entry`
   for output formats, `ffmpeg -h muxer=entry`

Each format readout will show something like,

```
Muxer matroska [Matroska]:
    Common extensions: mkv.
    Mime type: video/x-matroska.
    Default video codec: h264.
...
```

or

```
Demuxer avi [AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)]:
    Common extensions: avi.
...
```

Then you can collect all extensions from the `Common extensions` entries.

Comment: Thanks for the attention to detail and quick response.  This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: To get a nice list, run `ffmpeg -demuxers -hide_banner | tail -n +5 | cut -d' ' -f4 | xargs -i{} ffmpeg -hide_banner -h demuxer={} | grep 'Common extensions' | cut -d' ' -f7 | tr ',' $'\n' | tr -d '.'` Same for muxing, just replace `demux` with `mux`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the **Gyan's** answer, here's a python script I used to get all possible extension from ffmpeg, fot its muxers and demuxers:

```py
import subprocess, re

ffmpeg = 'c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'

LINE_PATTERN = r' +\S+ +(\S+)'
EXT_PATTERN = r'Common extensions: (.+)\.'

# Get demuxers
output = subprocess.getoutput([ffmpeg, '-hide_banner', '-demuxers'])
lines = output.split('\n')[4:]

demuxers = {}
for line in lines:
  demuxer = re.findall(LINE_PATTERN, line)[0]
  
  info = subprocess.getoutput([ffmpeg, '-hide_banner', '-h', f'demuxer={demuxer}'])
  exts = re.findall(EXT_PATTERN, info)
  if exts:
    demuxers[demuxer] = exts[0].split(',')


# Get muxers
output = subprocess.getoutput([ffmpeg, '-hide_banner', '-muxers'])
lines = output.split('\n')[4:]

muxers = {}
for line in lines:
  muxer = re.findall(LINE_PATTERN, line)[0]

  info = subprocess.getoutput([ffmpeg, '-hide_banner', '-h', f'muxer={muxer}'])
  exts = re.findall(EXT_PATTERN, info)
  if exts:
    muxers[muxer] = exts[0].split(',')


# Write extensions
file_name = 'ffmpeg_extensions.txt'
f = open(file_name, 'w')

exts = set()
for ext in demuxers.values():
  [exts.add(x.strip()) for x in ext]
for ext in muxers.values():
  [exts.add(x.strip()) for x in ext]
for ext in sorted(exts):
  f.write(ext + '\n')

f.close()

print('Extensions written to file: ' + file_name)
```

Comment: That script never halts for me.

Comment: For me it takes ~1m to execute as it calls the ffmpeg executable for every muxer and demuxer. You can insert `print(line)` for example inside each `for line` and check if it's progressing. Tested it with v 6.0 of ffmpeg for Windows.