# How to determine if ffmpeg supports an extension for the output file?

Tags: ffmpeg

When ffmpeg is given a command to output a file with a particular extension it presumably runs an internal algorithm do determine what encoder and/or muxer to use with it. Is there a command to find out whether a particular output extension is supported or not? Like in imagemagick with a command `magick identify -list format`?

`ffmpeg -h muxer=mp4` does not work with image formats like `jpg` and `png` even though ffmpeg is capable of outputting images of these formats.

`ffmpeg -formats` does not seem reliable enough as well as instead of `jpg` it has `singlejpg` and does not include `png` (only `apng` and `png_pipe`).

Comment: Can't you just pipe your output to Imagemagick where you can get whatever format you want?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50069235